# How to import a dart file from a directory from a local file?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am a student and very new to flutter/dart so I am incredibly sorry if I make mistakes along the way or just sound like a noob.

I have an application I am currently working on and I have some classes I want to import.

I want to make a simple console application, but do not copy and to always have the same updated classes how do I import the classes from a folder.

I tried the following:

made a folder called "WindowsApp"

made another folder called "lib" (because for some reason it is the only I can run the main)

made a file "main.dart"

and had the following code

```dart
import '<directory>\\foo.dart';

void main(){ 
 print('test');
}
```

Does it say that the directory doesn't exist? In java, I remember doing something similar and it worked, but I seem to not have the same logic work here.

The research I have done it is still foggy as to what to do because one answer is to use Source, another provided what I wanted, but didn't show the code and the code that was shown introduced a new thing called the library. Is there no simple way like java where you just put in the directory and that is it?

Do I need a full-blown project with a YAML and all if I wanted to use APIs and such?

Comment: Path should be like this `/foo.dart` , not `\foo.dart`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it seems that you have made one simple mistake, using the wrong key '\' instead of '/'

you can check for instructions on how to import packages [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages#css-example)

and you can use the same method to import your own stuff, for example:

say you have this folder structure:

```
├── /lib
│   ├── main.dart
├───├── /random
│   ├───├── another.dart
---
```

to import another.dart to main.dart you would have this, using your example:

```dart
import 'package:<yourappname_on_pubspec.yaml>/random/another.dart';

void main(){ 
 print('test');
}
```

OR

```dart
import '../random/another.dart';

void main(){ 
 print('test');
}
```

hope this made it clear

Comment: what is the difference between "package:...." and import '../random/....'. I guess my question is that when should I use the keyword "package". Looks like I am going go with you second option I am just interested in the keyterm 'package'

Comment: @PedroCelis there's no difference between both, they have the same result. 
The firs one is an absolute path and the second one is relative the file you are writing.
But the default (and to mantain a standard) method for dart is the first one, since even if you move that file (main.dart) to another folder, the import would still work.

Comment: @PedroCelis if the answer solves your question, please accept it as the answer.

Comment: I used your method and it is not working. C:/Users/Name/Desktop/Dev/my_application/lib/File.dart....this is the location of the second file C:/Users/Name/Desktop/Dev/second_file

Comment: @PedroCelis So your second file is not inside your project folder? you can't do that. Importing files from outside lib/ is not supposed to work. This would prevent publishing packages to pub.dartlang.org because only lib/ and bin/ are downloaded when added to dependencies. Try placing your file inside your project /lib folder.